# Check color in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, format

I'm struggling a bit with Google App Script. I'm looking to write a simple script that checks when a user changes a colour, and, if it's wrong, corrects it.

Here's my code so far:

```
    function onEdit(e) {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var r = sheet.getActiveRange();

  if (r.getBackground() != '#D9EAD3') {

    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert('Wrong colour!');

    r.setBackground('#D9EAD3');

  }

}
```

It almost works...However.

- it only works when text is changed, not colour (there doesn't appear to be an onFormat option)
- it appears to change cell a1 every time.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

***EDIT***
That's a great help - thanks, Sandy. My code now looks like this:

```
function formatWasChanged(e) {

  var r = e.range;
  if (r.getBackground() != '#D9EAD3' && r.getBackground() != '#FFFFFF') {

    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert('Wrong colour!');

    r.setBackground('#D9EAD3');

  }

}
```

I've also defined this as a project trigger, called on change. Unfortunately, it's still not running when I test it on my spreadsheet - **var r = e.range;** appears to fail when I run it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an installable "Change" trigger.  That can check for:

Quote from Google Documentation:

> e.changeType - The type of change (EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT, or OTHER)

Note the FORMAT type of change.

[Google Documentation - Change Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)

You must click the 'Resources' menu, and choose 'Current Project Triggers' in the code editor.

```
function formatWasChanged(e) {
  Logger.log('e.changeType: ' + e.changeType);

  if (e.changeType === 'FORMAT') {
    Logger.log('Its a FORMAT changeType: ');

  };
};
```

If you do stay with the `onEdit()` trigger,

Don't use:

```
var r = sheet.getActiveRange();
```

To get the range that was **edited**, use:

```
var r = e.range;
```

Google documentation:

> e.range - A Range object, representing the cell or range of cells that were edited